# Undefined variable: crud - DOMPdf

Tags: laravel, crud, dompdf, undefined

Estoy intentando imprimir una pagina utilizando Dompdf en laravel. Señalo la ruta y llego a la función donde utilizo  loadView() que es donde se genera el error "Undefined variable: crud".
Se que tengo que pasar las variables en  $data, pero crud no se como pasarlo y me genera error en varias instancias.

**ENLACE**

`<a href="{{route('pdfStream'), }}" target="_blank" > Imprimir </a>`

**RUTA**

`Route::get('/pdf', 'App\Http\Controllers\PDFController@pdfStream')->name('pdfStream');`

FUNCION

public function pdfStream(Request $request){

```
    $data = array('nombre'=>'John', 'fecha'=>'1/29/15');
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('vendor/backpack/crud/paciente/historia_clinica', $data);
    return $pdf->stream('historia_clinica.pdf');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes renderizar la vista aparte sin problemas

```
$view = View::make('vendor/backpack/crud/paciente/historia_clinica',compact('var1', 'var2', 'var3'))->render();
$pdf  = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');

$pdf->loadHTML($view)
```